# About semiconvex and semiconcave functions in geodesically complete CAT(0) spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I posted this question a while ago but had no luck. So I'm trying again. Let $(X,d)$ be a proper, geodesically complete $CAT(0)$ space and let $\Sigma_x X$ be the space of directions at a point $x\in X$. I'm trying to prove the following regularity results concerning the differential of Lipschitz and semiconcave/semiconvex functions.

1. Let $\phi : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz $2\lambda$-concave function. Then the function
   $$x \mapsto \sup_{v \in \Sigma_x X} d_x \phi (v)$$
   is lower semicontinuous.
2. Let $\psi : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz $2\lambda$-convex function. Then the function
   $$x \mapsto \sup_{v \in \Sigma_x X} d_x \psi (v)$$
   is upper semicontinuous.

My attempt:

1. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Let $x \in X$ and let $y \in X$ such that $y \neq x$ and
   $$\frac{\phi(y) - \phi(x)}{d(x,y)} \ge \sup_{v \in \Sigma_x X} d_x \phi (v) - \varepsilon.$$

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences converging to $x$ and $y$ respectively. The $2\lambda$-concavity of $\phi$ gives

$$d_{x_n} \phi ( \uparrow_{x_n}^{y_n} ) \ge \frac{\phi(y_n) - \phi(x_n) - \lambda d^2(x_n,y_n)}{d(x_n,y_n)} \ge \frac{\phi(y) - \phi(x)}{d(x,y)} - \varepsilon,$$
where the last inequality is obtained when $n$ is big enough and by choosing $y$ close enough to $x$. Therefore, we get

$$\sup_{v \in \Sigma_{x_n} X} d_{x_n} \phi (v) \ge \sup_{v \in \Sigma_x X} d_x \phi (v) - 2 \varepsilon,$$

and by taking the infimum limit, we get the result.

2. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence converging to $x$, let $(y_n)$ be a sequence converging to some $y \neq x$ and such that

$$d_{x_n} \psi (\uparrow_{x_n}^{y_n}) \ge \sup_{v \in \Sigma_{x_n} X} d_{x_n} \psi (v) - \varepsilon, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Let $\gamma^n : [0,1] \to X$ be the unit speed geodesic connecting $x_n$ and $y_n$. By Arzela-Ascoli theorem, there exists a subsequence of the sequence of curves $(\gamma^n)$ (not relabeled here) converging uniformly to $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$, which is the unit speed geodesic connecting $x$ and $y$. Furthermore, the $2\lambda$ convexity of $\psi$ give

\begin{align*}
\sup_{v \in \Sigma_{x_n} X } \{d_{x_n} \psi ( v ) \} - \varepsilon &\le  d_{x_n} \psi (\uparrow_{x_n}^{y_n} ) = d_{x_n} \psi ( \uparrow_{x_n}^{\gamma^{n}_t})  \\
&\le \frac{\psi(\gamma^{n}_t) - \psi(x_n) - \lambda d^2(x_n,\gamma^{n}_t)}{d(x_n,\gamma^{n}_t)} \\
&\le \frac{\psi(\gamma_t) - \psi(x)}{d(x,\gamma_t)} + \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
where the last inequality holds when taking $t$ small enough and $n$ big enough. Hence we get

\begin{align*}
 \limsup_{x_n \to x} \sup_{v \in \Sigma_{x_n} X } \{d_{x_n} \psi ( v )\} \le \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\psi(\gamma_t) - \psi(x)}{d(x,\gamma_t)} + 2\varepsilon  &= \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\psi(\gamma_t) - \psi(x)}{t} + 2\varepsilon \\ &\le  \sup_{v \in \Sigma_{x} X} \{d_{x} \psi ( v ) \} + 2\varepsilon.
\end{align*}